# Isabelle won't generate code for my recursive function without a termination proof

Tags: isabelle

If I write a non-trivial recursive function (i.e. using `function` rather than `fun`), then the code generator refuses to execute my function unless I supply a termination proof -- even a `sorry`-proof suffices. Here is my minimal working example (don't worry about the contents of the `foo` function, it's just a random function with a non-trivial termination proof):

```
theory Misc imports 
  Main 
  "~~/src/HOL/Library/Code_Target_Numeral"
begin

function foo :: "nat list ⇒ nat list list"
where
  "foo G = (
  if G = [] then
    map concat [[G]] 
  else
    concat (map foo (map (λx. [Suc x]) (tl G)))
  )"
by auto
termination sorry

value "foo [1,2,3]"

end
```

Currently the `value` command returns the correct result `"[]"`. But if I remove the line `termination sorry`, then the `value` command returns `"foo [1, 2, 3]"`.

Is there any way to make the code generator execute `foo`, without having to spoil my theory file with the horrible `sorry`? I don't want to actually *do* the termination proof because it's a really hard proof.

Comment: Sorry, but before having the termination proof you cannot even be sure that your function declaration makes sense at all ;). So I'm, for one, glad that code generation is not possible without such a proof (that's, in my opinion, one of the main points of using Isabelle). Inserting `termination sorry` in the cases were you don't care about correctness does not seem very tedious to me. And the advantage is that you immediately see that something potentially dangerous is going on.

Comment: @chris Fair enough. Feel free to answerify your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris' comment answers your question, but I thought I would just give an example.

A non-terminating function has the ability to introduce unsoundness, which is why a proof of termination is required (or at very least a `sorry`).

For example, with the following function definition:

```
function f :: "nat ⇒ nat" where "f n = f n + 1"
  by auto

termination
  sorry
```

we can then go on to prove `False`:

```
lemma "False"
  by (metis a.f.elims add_eq_self_zero if_1_0_0)
```

The unsoundness comes from the non-termination of the function.

In your concrete example, the termination proof isn't too hard: you can see that the length of the list `G` is always decreasing. We can then just use a measure function and show that it decreases, as so:

```
termination
  (* Give Isabelle a termination relation. We say that the length
   * of the parameter is strictly decreasing to 0. *)
  apply (relation "measure length", simp)

  (* simplify *)
  apply clarsimp

  (* Sledgehammer can now solve this goal, but by hand is a bit neater. *)
  apply (drule length_pos_if_in_set, clarsimp)
  done
```

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that the `relation` method can be used to directly specify the desired measure in a termination proof. E.g., `apply (relation "measure length")` as first step. In this specific case it won't help much, but when the remainder of the proof goes through with some automatic method it is a nice shorthand to use `by (relation "...") auto` (also note that `wf_measure` is declared as `iff` and thus used by the automatic methods already).

Comment: @chris: I didn't know about the `relation` method. It does indeed make the termination proof simpler, so I have updated the proof above. Thanks!